# Alignment of jdouble wrong for JNI function on Motorola Defy

Tags: android, java-native-interface

On some devices I get the problem that double values are not transferred correctly to C++.
It looks like the first part of a double value gets copied in the second half of the target variable and the second half into the first half of the next target variable.

Question:

How can I change the alignment for the JNI function parameters?

More details for interested readers:

All variables are defined as double in java and jdouble in the C++ files.
On all devices ByteOrder.nativeOrder() reports LITTLE_ENDIAN.

On normal devices I get the expected hex string in reversed order:

```
1A: 2.25   -> expected: 4002000000000000, found: 0000000000000240 (works)
```

When called on the Motorola Defy, I get weird results. I call a function with 3 jdouble variables. First (1A-1C) and second run (2A-2C) are shown here:

```
1A: 2.25   -> expected: 4002000000000000, found: 005c814000000000
1B: 0.1275 -> expected: 3fc051eb851eb852, found: 0000024052B81E85 (second half of 1B?)
1C: 2.25   -> expected: 4002000000000000, found: EB51C03F00000000 (first half of 1B?)

2A: 5.25   -> expected: 4015000000000000, found: 005C814000000000
2B: 0.3045 -> expected: 3fd37ced916872b1, found: 00001530B1726891 (second half of 2B?)
2C: 5.25   -> expected: 4015000000000000, found: ED7CD33F00000000 (first half of 32?)
```

For the "expeceted" hex string I use Long.toHexString(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(dV)) in Java, gives the same results as calculated with Robert's link.

On the problem device (Motorola Defy), the "expected" values are the same, so the Java part seems to work fine, but the "found" values inside the JNI-code are completely different. I don't really see a pattern here, same input leads to different output and the bytes are not even near those in "expected".

First impression is, that the values get never set and it uses whatever is at that memory location? What could be the cause and any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Have you checked which data you get on C++ side (just print the jdouble 64bit value as byte[8] in hexadecimal form). According to [this page](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/Decimal.html) you should get 0x402199999999999A for the double value 8.8.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I have updated the question. Is this a known issue with older phones and different byte/bit order? And more importantly, how do I fix it? Define some compilere flags? In Java? In the NDK?

Comment: The first version seems to be in big endian format, the second in little endian format (reversed byte order) and the third is a total fail.

Comment: Reworked the question to be better understandable, now the box with 1A-3C contains all values that fail.

Comment: Fixed by changing order of parameters from (JNIEnv *env, jclass thiz, jobject bitmap1, jobject bitmap2, jdouble x1, jdouble y1, jdouble x2, jdouble y2) to (JNIEnv *env, jclass thiz, jdouble x1, jdouble y1, jdouble x2, jdouble y2, jobject bitmap1, jobject bitmap2) fixed the problem for us, looks like the Bitmap-Pointers are treated different at the start or end of the parameter list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by changing order of parameters from

(JNIEnv *env, jclass thiz, jobject bitmap1, jobject bitmap2, jdouble x1, jdouble y1, jdouble x2, jdouble y2)

to

(JNIEnv *env, jclass thiz, jdouble x1, jdouble y1, jdouble x2, jdouble y2, jobject bitmap1, jobject bitmap2)

Looks like the Bitmap-Pointers are treated different at the start or end of the parameter list.